# Making multiple input objects fit inline without wrapping/horisontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

Using standard Bootstrap 3 framework. It looks OK on PC browser (see screenshot below) but the Lunch checkbox makes the scrollbar appear. On my phone however, the input boxes cover the entire width, and the checkbox is to the right of the screen.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get all 3 elements appear on the same row, and adjust themself to correct size to fit in width?

Also, why doesn't the elements have any margins?

```
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <div class="form-group flex">
            <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
                    <input type='text' value='07:00' class="form-control fraTimepicker">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></span>
                    <input type='text' value='15:00' class="form-control tilTimepicker">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn active">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="lunchCheckbox">
                            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i><span>Lunch?</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you check this: https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/K03yV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are using both bootstrap column and css flex. If you are relying on the bootstrap 3 don't mix it with flex. Flex will always force the layout to stay in one line.

Try removing the flex and wrap the rows with a div of class "container" or "container-fluid"

And using the class col-xs-3 instead of col-sm-3 will keep the columns in the mobile layout as well.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

if this does not solve your problem you have to use the media queries and have to define max-width / width for the elements inside.

But its always better to stack the elements one per row utilizing the full width in mobile devices to avoid the overflow and it will also provide better user experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about container-fluid!

Comment: Glad I could help you